# RSpec Newbie: "Update attributes => false" not being recognised

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Just starting out with RSpec. Everything is going smoothly, except for one spec with nested controllers.

I'm trying to ensure that when a 'comment' resource (nested under 'post') is updated with invalid parameters, it renders the 'edit' template. I'm struggling to get rspec to recognise the :update_attributes => false trigger. If anyone has any suggestions, they'd be very appreciated. Attempted code below:

```
  def mock_comment(stubs={})
    stubs[:post] = return_post
    stubs[:user] = return_user
    @mock_comment ||= mock_model(Comment, stubs).as_null_object
  end

  describe "with invalid paramters" dog
    it "re-renders the 'edit' template" do
      Comment.stub(:find).with("12") { mock_comment(:update_attributes => false) }
      put :update, :post_id => mock_comment.post.id, :id => "12"
      response.should render_template("edit")
    end
  end
```

And the controller:

```
  def update
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.update_attributes(params[:comment])
        flash[:notice] = 'Post successfully updated'
        format.html { redirect_to(@comment.post) }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @comment.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end
```

And finally, the error:

```
 Failure/Error: response.should render_template("edit")
   expecting <"edit"> but rendering with <"">.
   Expected block to return true value.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite an interesting problem. A quick fix is to simply replace the block form of `Comment.stub`:

```
Comment.stub(:find).with("12") { mock_comment(:update_attributes => false) }
```

with an explicit `and_return`:

```
Comment.stub(:find).with("12").\
  and_return(mock_comment(:update_attributes => false))
```

As to why these two forms should produce different results, that's a bit of a head-scratcher. If you play around with the first form you'll see that the mock is actually returning `self` instead of `false` when the stubbed method is called. That's tells us it hasn't stubbed the method (since it's specified as a null object).

The answer is that when passing in a block, the block is only executed when the stubbed method is called, not when the stub is defined. So when using the block form, the following call:

```
put :update, :post_id => mock_comment.post.id, :id => "12"
```

is executing `mock_comment` for the first time. Since `:update_attributes => false` is not being passed in, the method is not stubbed, and the mock is returned rather than `false`. When the block invokes `mock_comment` it returns `@mock_comment`, which doesn't have the stub.

Contrariwise, using the explicit form of `and_return` invokes `mock_comment` immediately. It would probably be better to use the instance variable instead of calling the method each time to make the intent clearer:

```
it "re-renders the 'edit' template" do
  mock_comment(:update_attributes => false)
  Comment.stub(:find).with("12") { @mock_comment }
  put :update, :post_id => @mock_comment.post.id, :id => "12"
  response.should render_template("edit")
end
```